# ELK queries - multiple query params

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm using an ELK stack to visualize data from server log files. I have a parameter called "_type" and it's unique for each server. It's all working fine, and I can do a (URL) query like:

```
query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'_type:server1'))
```

But I can't figure out how to have two (or more) "_type" parameters in my query. I would like to see "_type=server1" and "_type=server2" in the same chart.

Isn't that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Try with `query:'_type:server1 OR _type:server2'`.

Comment: I just ran a small test, and it seems like it's working! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `query:'_type:server1 OR _type:server2'`. Relevant documentation section [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax).